# Another std::bad_alloc at memory location

Tags: c++

I searched for this kind of error and found a lot. unfortunately no thread really helped me.

I have image files which I save in an `array` or a `vector` or what ever.

After about 1.8 GB (~1439 Images) the error `std::bad_alloc` at memory location occurs. So I tried to declared the `array` in different ways but every time the same error occurs.

```
Image* img;
Image img[180000];
Image* img = new Image[180000]

vector<Image> img;
```

(The 180k would be 1 minute of Frames). Its not really important to record 1 minute but it would be nice to save more than ~1439 Frames. Or at least to understand why this error occurs or rather why it occurs at 1.8 GB.

Maybe someone could help or explain that to me?

PS: i use a 32bit System

---

The problem is, the time to save the images in an folder or something takes to long. Maybe I have to find a compression which allows me to save just the necessary information of the image in the array and then I can restore the frames when I am done.

I heard that you can convert an image just in a x and a y "line" which holds all these information. But how this works is another issue.

The answers from Mark Ingram were exactly what I needed to understand the problem. Thanks for that

edit: oh i see i explained my problem not enough. I did`t have the Images and load them in my programm. I have a Camera which records the frame with a frequency of 50Hz so while recording i have no time to save the frames.

Comment: There is no more than 1.8GB of contiguous memory to allocate `img[180000]`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Do you really need all the images at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've ran out of memory. On a 32bit system (on Windows at least) you can only allocate up to a maximum of ~2GB of memory. You need to dynamically load your data only when needed, and when you no longer need the image data, throw it away again.

In reality, the limit will be lower than 2GB, as memory is allocated in blocks (i.e. it isn't allocated contiguously). This means you will experience heap fragmentation if you mix small and large object allocations, and that will drastically reduce the amount of memory you can actually allocate.

Comment: Isn't that closer to 4GB?(2^32 = 4'294'967'296)

Comment: @Dahaka No, on Windows you can only allocate 2GB in a single process. See here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx (Memory Limits for Windows Releases)

Answer (score 1):

Store the images in a folder and load one at a time. 
Dynamic memory allocation is your friend.

There is nothing I could think of to accomplish by loading 18,000 images together. You are never going to process it even on a super computer.